# CSS: How to wrap text around a title (h1)?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I have a design with the title of the page in an `h1` to the right, with the text in a `p` on the left, in the same `div`. The text should wrap around the title (so break when it 'collides' with the title, but underneath it, it should use all the space in the `div`).

It doesn't work the same as with images, where you'd just use `float: left;` for the `p` and `float: right;` for the image, in this case, `h1`.

I could put the `h1` inside the `p`, but I thought I'd ask you guys first instead of making untidy code.

Comment: Like this - http://jsfiddle.net/njYnT/1/ ?

Comment: which browser are you using? Also please provide your relevant code

Comment: Please read the [faq]. [SO] isn't a forum, so don't waste your energy adding unnecessary greetings or signatures.

Comment: Very well. Take it easy, mate.

Comment: Ok, it had something to do with my `p` having the style of `display:inline-block;`; removed the whole display-attribute, works well now. :)

Comment: How is this question unclear or not useful?

Answer (score 4):

Just don't use `float:left` for the `<p>`, but only `float:right` for the `<h1>`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CFnsv/) there is a  quick example.

Answer (score 2):

Elisa is right,

You can take it even further by creating multiple elements within your heading and float all of them...

Like so: http://jsfiddle.net/jaap/CFnsv/74/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>
        <span>&ldquo;I love</span> 
        <span>deadlines.</span>
        <span>I love the</span>
        <span>whooshing</span>
        <span>noise they</span>
        <span>make ad</span>
        <span>they go</span>
        <span>by.&rdquo;</span>
    </h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ibh tortor, vulpu...
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor s... 
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container p{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h1{
    font-size:44px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height:36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #DAAB2B;
}
h1 span{
    float:right;
    text-align: right;
    clear:both;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

[image: Preview of floating multiple elements]

Answer (score 0):

You could create an outer div that contains two more divs, one floating left and the other floating right. Have the paragraph on the left and the H1 on the right. If you specify the width for the div on the right, the div on the left will automatically take up all the space till it encounters the div on the right.